# union types in tolua

Tags: c, lua

I think there is a bug in tolua regarding unions. If you have a declaration like this:

```
struct SDL_WindowEvent {
    int type;
    int windowID;
};

union SDL_Event {
    int type;
    SDL_WindowEvent window;
};

extern SDL_Event * create(void);
extern void frobnicate(SDL_Event *);
```

then it should be okay to have lua code like this:

```
event = create()
frobnicate(event)
print(event.window.windowId)
frobnicate(event)
```

But the second call to frobnicate(event) will fail with an error:

```
argument #1 is 'SDL_WindowEvent'; 'SDL_Event' expected.
```

A little poking at the debugger reveals that a tolua_pushusertype in the event.window access rewrites the type of my variable!

Here's what I've tried so far: From my declaration, tolua will create the following call for declaring the SDL_WindowEvent class:

```
tolua_cclass(tolua_S,"SDL_WindowEvent","SDL_WindowEvent","",NULL);
```

thus making the SDL_Event and SDL_WindowEvent two unrelated classes, not base classes of each other. Let's say I have code later on that is equivalent to the following:

```
tolua_pushusertype(tolua_S, event, "SDL_Event");
assert(tolua_isusertype(tolua_S,1,"SDL_Event",0,&tolua_err));
tolua_pushusertype(tolua_S, event->window, "SDL_WindowEvent");
assert(tolua_isusertype(tolua_S,2,"SDL_Event",0,&tolua_err));
```

then the assert in the fourth line will fail, because the value on the stack has magically changed type since the assert in line two. This is because tolua_pushusertype() changes it - foo and foo.window have the same address, and internally, tolua only tracks one type per each address. tolua_isusertype() would have been satisfied if the object had been of base type SDL_Event, but that would require the tolua_cclass declaration above to have a "SDL_Event" as its fourth argument. When I manually fix that, both asserts pass, but I can't manually change that each time - I would like to fix tolua to do this, but I don't
understand it well enough yet to do that. I don't even know if that would be the right thing to do.

I'm using tolua 5.1.4, but the same problem occurs with tolua++ 1.92.3.

Is there something I am doing wrong, first of all? Is there a way I can rewrite my declaration to have this work with tolua as-is? Or, failing that, a fix I can apply to tolua that makes this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! The solution was to edit my .pkg file like so:

```
struct SDL_WindowEvent : SDL_Event {
    int type;
    int windowID;
};
```

This makes the class hierarchy explicit for tolua. I was too focused on the .pkg contents being valid C code, it would seem.

Comment: If you found the solution, please mark the question as solved.

Comment: SO made me wait two days before I was allowed to accept my own answer.